# Unexpected behavior of expectation method in sympy stats module

Tags: python, statistics, sympy, integral

I am trying to evaluate the expectation of a function of a normal random variable using Sympy 0.7.4.1

```
a, mu = symbols('x mu', real=True)
sigma = symbols('sigma', positive=True)
X = Normal("X", mu, sigma)
expr1 = (sigma**2 - (X-mu)**2)
print E(expr1)
```

This gives 0 as expected since I am subtracting the variance from itself. Now I multiply `expr` by a constant `1/a`

```
expr2 = (sigma**2 - (X-mu)**2)/a
print E(expr2)
```

Again, this gives 0 as expected.

However, if I multiply `expr` by the factor `1/(a-1)`,

```
expr3 = (sigma**2 - (X-mu)**2)/(a-1)
print E(expr3)
```

Sympy returns an unevaluated integral instead of 0.

```
Integral(sqrt(2)*(sigma**2 - (X - mu)**2)*exp(-(X -
         mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))/(2*sqrt(pi)*sigma*(x - 1)), (X, -oo, oo))
```

Since `a` is an arbitrary constant, why is the expectation of `expr2` and `expr3` different?

Checking in Mathematica, the equivalent

```
Expectation[(\[Sigma]^2 - (\[Mu] - X)^2)/(a - 1), 
             X \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]]
```

gives 0 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider this to be a bug. Can you report it at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new?